# Draw graph with ovals tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Im trying to draw this graph with ovals (tikz). Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: We sure can! Can you help us help you by posting a M(non)WE? What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt. First, define styles for oval shape, dot, and line respectively. Use the `node` command to put those 5 corners with < internal name > by using the relative coordinates. The remaining nodes can be found/located via `($(n1)!x!(n2)$)` coordinate calculation automatically, where x=[0 1]. Lastly use `draw` command to connect lines.

```
\tikzset{
ell/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=2em,minimum width=8em,align=center},
line/.style={-,line width=0.5pt},
dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt},
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,shapes,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
ell/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=2em,minimum width=8em,align=center},
line/.style={-,line width=0.5pt},
dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[dot](a) {};
\node[dot,right=2cm of a] (b){};
\node[dot,below=2cm of b] (c){};
\node[dot,left= 2cm of c] (d){};
\node[dot,yshift=-1cm] at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$)(e) {};
\node[dot] at ($(d)!0.5!(a)$)(f){};
\node[dot] at ($(f)!0.5!(a)$)(g){};
\node[dot] at ($(f)!0.5!(d)$)(){};
\node[dot] at ($(d)!0.15!(f)$)(){};
\node[dot] at ($(d)!0.3!(f)$)(){};
\node[ell] at ($(a)!0.5!(b)$) {};
\node[ell,rotate=90] at ($(b)!0.5!(c)$) {};
\node[ell] at ($(c)!0.5!(d)$) {};
\node[ell,rotate=90] at ($(d)!0.5!(a)$) {};
\draw[line] (e) -- (a);
\draw[line] (e) -- (b);
\draw[line] (e) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```